# Comparing 2 columns to produce an answer for column 3

Tags: excel

I need a formula, that looks for a number an entry in column A, then checks for yes or no (Y/N) in column B, and provides me with the answer from column C, the reason I require it is because whoever uses this sheet won't actually have access to the information (security reasons) so it will be in a hidden tab and this formula will be on a seperate sheet.

```
       A     B     C
row 1  13    Y     10
row 2  15    Y     11
row 3  15    N     12
row 4  17    Y     13
```

So in the above example, i want to be able to look for 15 and N, and it provide me with 12

Im sure it's fairly straight forward for you guys but I'm getting nowhere, please let me know if you need any further information and I hope my formatting is okay!

Comment: What have you tried? Is it possible to sort the table by column B=N or Y and then by column A?

Comment: The columns can be whatever way round makes it easier, I've tried VLookup but I couldn't figure out how to make it check 2 columns and not just the 1, I'm not very excel savvy.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a case of a two column match. There are a few ways of performing this lookup; I prefer this standard formula method.

[image: INDEX double lookup]

The formula in G2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$998)+((A$2:A$999<>E$2)+(B$2:B$999<>F$2))*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

I've made that a bit more complicated than you requested. If you fill the formula down, you will receive successive matches (as per the modified data in the image above).

Comment: Thanks mate you're a hero! I'd have never figured this out in a month of Sundays